# MongoDB Morphia Update multi=true VS bulk update

Tags: mongodb, morphia, mongo-java-driver

I want to update 10,000 documents in a single web request. I intend to update only one field (which is indexed) in all the documents matched with some criteria with same value.
I see morphia 1.3.2  always set multi=true parameter in update call. Is it enough for updating 10,000 document? Or there are any bulk update functionality in morphia.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you.

```
Query<Entity> query = datastore.createQuery(Entity.class);
query.filter("name = ", "xxx");
UpdateOperations<Entity> updateOperations = datastore.createUpdateOperations(Entity.class).set
    ("yyy", 200);
UpdateResults updateResults = datastore.update(query, updateOperations, false, null);
```

All the documents in the collection with name = 'xxx' will now have all their 'yyy' attribute equal to 200.